# How to fix maven error prone compiling issue

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, errorprone

I have a java project on Git and I used Intellij(2020.3 Ultimate) git plugin to download the code to my local, after that I did the followings

1. Installed the Oracle JDK 11
2. Configured the Oracle JDK 11 as my java compiler in Intellij for this project.
3. Downloaded the Maven 3.6.3 to my local and integrated with my Intellij.
4. After that I can see the install under Lifecycle in Maven view.
5. Then I clicked on install

After a while, the maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @xxxx is running. Then suddenly, I got this error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/an/myproject/api/internal/src/TransanctionService.java:[306,15] error: An unhandled exception was thrown by the Error Prone static analysis plugin.
 Please report this at https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/new and include the following:
 error-prone version: 2.3.2
 BugPattern: TypeParameterUnusedInFormals
 Stack Trace:
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: bound
at com.google.errorprone.bugpatterns.TypeParameterUnusedInFormals.matchMethod(TypeParameterUnusedInFormals.java:73)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitMethod(ErrorProneScanner.java:890)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitMethod(ErrorProneScanner.java:146)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:898)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:82)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:83)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:43)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:90)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:105)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:113)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitClass(TreeScanner.java:187)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitClass(ErrorProneScanner.java:588)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitClass(ErrorProneScanner.java:146)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:808)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:82)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:83)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:43)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:105)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:113)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitCompilationUnit(TreeScanner.java:144)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitCompilationUnit(ErrorProneScanner.java:603)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitCompilationUnit(ErrorProneScanner.java:146)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:591)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:56)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:65)
at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScannerTransformer.apply(ErrorProneScannerTransformer.java:43)
at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneAnalyzer.finished(ErrorProneAnalyzer.java:151)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.MultiTaskListener.finished(MultiTaskListener.java:132)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1418)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1365)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:966)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:311)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:75)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess0(JavacCompiler.java:626)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcessWithProperClassloader(JavacCompiler.java:607)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:596)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:178)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I checked the dependency tree on my project, here is only one error prone invoked

```
+- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
```

Any one who have idea on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using JDK 11.0.1, the issue can be closed.